# RoutedCommands bound by sub elements never fire

Tags: wpf, xaml, routed-commands, routedcommand

I'm trying to get my head around RoutedCommands in WPF. I like how they decrease coupling between different UI elements and the models but I can't seem to make the bindings work for custom controls that are children to the window. I guess this will be some easy creds for any of you WPF wizards out there! :-)

Here's some example code that can be tried out:

The routed command:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Wpf.RoutedCommands
{
    public static class Commands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedCommand SayHi = new RoutedCommand();
    }
}
```

Main window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.RoutedCommands.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.RoutedCommands"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<!-- uncommenting the below makes it work but introduces coupling -->
<!--<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Commands.SayHi}" Executed="cmdSayHi" CanExecute="cmdCanSayHi"></CommandBinding>
</Window.CommandBindings>-->
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Say Hi!" Command="{x:Static local:Commands.SayHi}" />
    <local:Greeter x:Name="Greeter" />
</DockPanel>
```

Main window code:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Wpf.RoutedCommands
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // these two will be used if you uncomment the command bindings in XAML
        private void cmdCanSayHi(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) => e.CanExecute = true;

        private void cmdSayHi(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) => Greeter.SayHi();
    }
}
```

Custom control ("Greeter") XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Wpf.RoutedCommands.Greeter"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.RoutedCommands"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Commands.SayHi}" Executed="cmdSayHi"  CanExecute="cmdCanSayHi"/>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="Label" />
</Grid>
```

Greeter code:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Wpf.RoutedCommands
{
    public partial class Greeter
    {
        public Greeter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdSayHi(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) => SayHi();

        private void cmdCanSayHi(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) => e.CanExecute = true;

        public void SayHi() => Label.Content = "Hi!";
    }
}
```

If you create a WPF project and use the above you will see that the button in main window is disabled. Debugging it shows that the `Greeter.cmdCanSayHi` method never gets called.

If you uncomment the dormant XAML in main window everything works. So: Why can I bind to commands from the window but not from its child controls? Is it to do with rendering timing or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RoutedCommand` searches the visual tree from the focused element and *up* for an element that has a matching `CommandBinding` and then executes the `Execute` delegate for this particular `CommandBinding`.

Your `UserControl` is located *below* the `Button` in the element tree.

Comment: Well, that sure explains it. Do you also know why routed commands has been designed like that?